# ruby socket issue

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpsocket

i'm still kind of newbie to ruby, but i became used on using ruby sockets, cause i used the 'Socket' class many times, and so i having full control to my sockets and their options.

the thing is i'm trying to make it a little easy for me, so i'm trying to use the 'TCPSocket' class ,witch (i guess) doesn't give u much control as the 'Socket' class.

my script looks like this:

```
require 'socket'
client = TCPSocket.open('5.5.5.5', '5555')
client.send("msg", 0) # 0 means standard packet
client.close
```

the question is, what is suppose to be instead of the '0' on the send line ?? and if '0' means standard packet, what other than standard can exist there, is it some control over the TCP packet ?? if so, then it will be much easier for me than writing the whole socket by hand using the 'Socket' class.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `send` is the `flags` parameter. It gets passed onto the the `send` system call. You'll normally want to leave this at 0.

On my system, according to the man page, the other possible flags are:

```
#define MSG_OOB        0x1  /* process out-of-band data */
#define MSG_DONTROUTE  0x4  /* bypass routing, use direct interface */
```